# Doubts about the proof of $q^*q = qq^*$ property for quaternions.

Tags: proof-explanation, quaternions

I have a problem with the proof of this quaternions property, included below.
$(q^∗)^∗ = [s, −(−v)] = [s, v] = q$，where $q = [s, v]$ and $v = [x, y, z]$.
$$q^∗q = (q^∗)(q^∗)^∗= ∥q^∗∥^2= s^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2= ∥q∥^2= qq^∗$$
so we got $q^*q = qq^*$.

Sorry my question is not clearly , my problem is why 
$$q^∗(q^∗)^∗=||q^∗||^2$$ not a $$q^∗(q^∗)^∗=||q^∗||^{{2}∗}$$
Why in the last equation we lost one of the conjugate marks?

Comment: What are those funny brackets supposed to be, what is $s, v$ and later $s,x, y, z$?

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's not clear about which conjugate 'mark' are you asking about. Include it in question instead of answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about which conjugate are you asking, so let's go step by step.
$$q^*q = q^*(q^*)^* $$
Here we used the property $(q^*)^* = q$ proved earlier.

$$q^*(q^*)^* = ||q^*||^2 $$
Here, we used that $rr^* = ||r||^2$ with $r = q^*$.

$$||q^*||^2 = s^2+x^2+y^2+z^2 $$
Here is the definition, $||q^*||^2 = s^2+(-x)^2+(-y)^2+(-z)^2 = s^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$, the author didn't bother with writing out the step in between.

$$s^2+x^2+y^2+z^2 = ||q||^2 $$
This is also the definition.
$$||q||^2 = qq^* $$ Here the property $rr^* = ||r||^2$ is used again, this time with $r = q$.

Comment: Thanks your anwer, where $|q^∗||^2$ is equal $|q^∗||^2*$ because the $|q^∗||^2$ is real number not have a conjugate ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. $(||q^*||^2)^* = ||q^*||^2$, yes

Answer (score 1):

Conjugate operation is [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)), so $(q^*)^* = q$.

Thus, since $qq^*$ is real, $qq^* = (qq^*)^*=q^*(q^*)^*=q^*q$.